# BlueSnap API - VaultedShopper FirstName and LastName

Tags: bluesnap

I'm creating an integration for the BlueSnap payment API.  I'm using the Hosted Payment Fields solution.  So when I create a VaultedShopper I just supply the Hosted Payment Fields token.  However, the other mandatory fields for the POST vaulted-shoppers call are FirstName and LastName.

If I supply FirstName and LastName, then the call works OK and the response includes the new ID - but with empty FirstName and LastName.

So I'm wondering what is the point of these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide first and last name in the request, they must be returned in the response. Keep in mind that JSON fields are case sensitive, so if you are sending "FirstName", the API will probably ignore it. Make sure you are sending "firstName" and "lastName".

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I don't actually need to send the firstName and lastName anyway.  However [the BlueSnap API doc](https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-JSON/docs/create-vaulted-shopper) implies they are mandatory.  I'll try removing them altogether.  I'll post an update when I do.